# xpath query to find the root element attribute value

Tags: c#

Most of the time i was trying to write xpath query by myself and fails all the time :(. Again i got in to problem to find the value

here is my xml

```
<Tail xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Id="45000061" CreateDateTime="2010-03-08T16:02:52.512+11:00" Type="Actual" Sender="DRNA" Receiver="Lawson">
```

Am trying to find the "ID" value in my root node (that's suppose to be "45000061")

Any help please.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xpath expression `/Tail/@Id` you get you the `Id` attribute value.

Comment: thanks a lot Bala R. It works like a champ,is this anyway i can say in my xpath query find //@id in the root node rather name mentioning the root name ?

Answer (score 0):

This site has a great free tool for building XPath Expressions (XPath Builder).

http://www.bubasoft.net/

Make your xpath expression work in the tool and then put it in your code.